# Unknown error in simple code (Python)

Tags: python

I wrote a simple love program in which for every vowel the user scores points that are the outputted at the end. There is an unknown error in the code and I am unable to notice this so if someone could point this out to me I'd be grateful.

```
awesome=0
name=input("Enter your name, wasteman")
for char in name:
    if char in ["a","e","i","o",u"]:
        awesome += 1
print("your awesome level is: " + str(awesome))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
["a","e","i","o",u"] <- missing opening quote  around `u`
```

It should be:

```
["a","e","i","o","u"]
```